# How to wait till progressbar disapper?

Tags: protractor

I want enter window and wait till element is present. Problem is, when i enter this window, this element is present and clickable, but after short time progressbar apper, and window is blocked till this progressbar works. How to wait properly for elements ?

I tried below code, doesn't work, but it show what i want obtain (click addButton, wait for progressbar or 5sec passed, and then wait for element id displayed.

```
this.openWindow = function(addButton, progressbar, targetElement){
    addButton.click().then(function(){
        browser.driver.wait(progressbar.isDisplayed(), 5000).then(function(){
            browser.driver.wait(targetElement.isDisplayed(), 5000);
        });
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout [official documentation for stalenessOf](https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorExpectedConditions.prototype.stalenessOf):

You should do something like this

```
this.openWindow = function(addButton, progressbar) {
    var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
    return addButton.click().then(function(){
        return browser.driver.wait(EC.stalenessOf(progressbar), 5000, 'Progress bar was not hidden within 5 sec');
    });
};
```

And then you can use your function like this

```
openWindow(addButton, progressbar).then(...)
```

The code above will be resolved when progress bar has been hidden or will fail if time is out.

If progress bar is not completely removed from DOM, you can also try [invisibilityOf](https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorExpectedConditions.prototype.invisibilityOf)

Comment: Looks like this simple one resolve my problem... Thx!